# Scraping third party tool using selenium in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have to scrape a third party tool using python selenium.

I am successful until opening the web page and clicking on the link.
When I click on the link, it will open a third party tool and then I am unable to scrape that tool.

```
url="xxxxxx" 
driver.get(url)
box = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
      (By.NAME, "domain")))
name = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user")
passwd = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "password")))
login_button=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "rightDoor")
name.send_keys(username)
passwd.send_keys(password)
login_button.click()
mon_tools=driver.find_element(By.ID, "folderLink_1")
mon_tools.click()
country=driver.find_element(By.ID, "folderLink_0")
country.click()
MWM_primary=driver.find_element(By.ID, "idCitrix.MPS.App.Farm1.MWM_0020Primary")
MWM_primary.click()
```

after this a new window(third party tool) opens and i am not able to get the control to that window.

---

Comment: You may want to add some code, why and where it is failing exactly.

Comment: i have added the code, pls check it and provide the solution

Comment: Ok, but do you get any error? Are you able to check the elements in that window? The ID of the link for that new window looks like some kind of Citrix app. If so, you will not be able to automate it, since Seleniums is used for Web Automation only.